# Why my custom workflow activity is not updated in database in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo-9

I'm using odoo 9 , I have a custom workflow related to MRP,when user changes the state of a record, this state is not reflected in database table (wkf_workitem)? Why ? Anyone?

Comment: Try to delete the workflow and update the module.

Comment: After deleting, on  upgrade it gives me follwing error
ParseError: "insert or update on table "wkf_transition" violates foreign key constraint "wkf_transition_act_from_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (act_from)=(10) is not present in table "wkf_activity".

Comment: Check your workflow transition id and make sure you use the same id you defined.

Comment: After deleting and upgrading application, workflow is not working correctly?@Zety

Comment: did  you check `wkf_transition_act_from` ?

Comment: Yes, I got it back, But what you had suggested me, wasn't a solution for my case, as my records got hanged in workflow and not be able to move back and forth

Comment: The log  message tell you that you use an id which is not defined try to change that.